# Create a object depending on incoming parameter

Tags: java, architecture

I have a object that accepts date in three different formats.

```
@Parameter(names = NEW_EXPIRY_TIME)
private LocalDateTime newExpiryTime;

@Parameter(names = EXTEND_FROM_TODAY)
private Integer extendFromToday;

@Parameter(names = EXTEND_FROM_PREVIOUS)
private Integer extendFromPrevious;
```

And I have a `CommandFactory` that should create `Command` that will process new date.

So far, when I had only one option, it was looking like:

```
public Command createUpdateExpiryCommand(UpdateExpiryConsoleCommandArgs args) {
        return new UpdateExpiryCommand(
                args.getSnapNameOrAlias(),
                args.getNewExpiryTime());
}
```

But now I have three options and need to create a Command with specific input parameter.

How to implement it properly?

Comment: uhm - the **strategy pattern** would describe the problem that you are facing... You would define a `Command` that would, during `execute()` handle these different parameters...

Comment: @MartinFrank is it possible to implement Strategy with different types of method argument?

Comment: another pattern that would help would be the **factory pattern** where you can create items (`Commands`) according to your *production plan* (new NYPizzaStore().createPizza("cheese"));`, see https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/6448/f07/lectures/21/21-Factory.pdf